# Parse - Linkedin Connect

Tags: ios, api, authentication, parse-platform, linkedin-api

I'm trying to build an iOS app with Parse using a Linkedin Connect.

1. User taps connect with Linkedin button and authorizes app
2. Redirected to the app
3. Need username, email and password to create `PFUser`

Has anyone found a way to create `PFUser`s using Linkedin data without asking for a password, and make the flow very similar to a Facebook Connect?

Answer (score 0):

Parse has offered APIs supporting logging in with twitter and Facebook. Since it has no direct support in Parse SDK. I think you have to make everything yourself. Maybe try to get the user's email from the linkedIn account and log in with this email as username.

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com now offer a generic OAuth library with a tutorial for authenticating GitHub accounts.

https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app

Answer (score 0):

This can help you : https://github.com/ahmetkgunay/LinkedinIOSHelper

This Library has features like authorizes app, getting access token, login with linkedIn, getting user's all informations, autoLogin if the accessToken is still valid.

Comment: As a reminder, this site's [policy for self-promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/253560) requires you to indicate your affiliation with this project in the answer, even though its a non-commercial, open-source project. The indication can be as simple as saying "My library" instead of "This library".

Comment: thnank you for your warning

Answer (score 0):

This repo may help you : https://github.com/alexruperez/PFLinkedInUtils

It provides utility functions for working with LinkedIn in a Parse application. If a _User with the LinkedIn id is found in Parse, it will retrieve the user. Otherwise a new _User will be created and sign up.